# How to add validation to contact form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am trying to add a contact form for users to fill and it will automatically email to the main account. I am unsure as to how I can add validation to the form so users are not able to click "Send Email" without filling in the fields.

I have currently tried adding `Website: <input type="url" name="website" required>`

app/views/contact_mailer/contact_email.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Contact Us Form</h1>
    <p>
      From: <%= @params['name'] %>
    </p>
    <p>
      Email: <%= @params['email'] %>
    </p>
    <p>
      Message: <%= @params['message'] %>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Contact form:

```
<h1>Any enquiries:</h1>
<center><form name="htmlform" method="get" action="/pages/send_form">
<table width="700px">



<form id="contact_form" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div class="row">
    <label for="name">Your Name:</label><br />
    <input id="name" class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label for="email">Your Email:</label><br />
    <input id="email" class="input" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label for="message">Your Message:</label><br />
    <textarea id="message" class="input" name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br />
  </div>
  <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send email" />

</form>
```

Currently, the email still sends to the account without any validation such as "You must complete this field"

Comment: you should add the code of your form

Comment: @Julien Please see updated post

Comment: why do you have 2 form elements?

Answer (score 0):

Create a model for your contact message. Something like:

```rb
class ContactEmail
  attr_accessor :name, :email, message
end
```

Then `include ActiveModel::Model` to get ActiveModel's validation and tell the model which fields to validate, like:

```rb
class ContactEmail
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name, :email, message
  validates :name, :email, message, presence: true
end
```

Finally, in your controller action, create a new ContactEmail with the form data and call the predicate method `valid?`.  And use `flash` to add an error message.

```rb
new_mail = ContactEmail.new(params['name'], params['email'], params['message'])
if new_mail.valid?
  ...
else
  flash.now[:error] = new_mail.errors.full_messages
end
```

Comment: the OP asked for a solution to prevent form submission, not going on a round trip and validating on the server side

Comment: While adding a `required` attribute is great, validation MUST be done on the server side to prevent tampering.  Doing both client side and server side validation is exactly what I would do.

Comment: i completely agree, i am just stating that that's not what the OP asked for

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exact sort of tampering does server-side validation prevent? And, `ContactEmail` isn't a rails model, is it? It seems like it's a PORO.

Comment: I can inspect the input element, view it in the developer tools and delete the `required` attribute off the DOM.  It will post, no problem.  Using the `required` attribute on the input is good UX but it shouldn't be relied upon.  And yes, it is a plain old ruby object, but the line `include ActiveModel::Model` gives it the methods I discussed.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the HTML form attributes? There is a required attribute so the user can't leave the field empty.
e.g.,

```
<input required id="email" class="input" name="email" type="email" value="" size="30"  />
```

you can also use the type = "email" and it will ensure some of the proper formatting.

(https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code of your form i see several problems:

- you have 2 `<form>` openings
- i dont see any `file` inputs so you don't need the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

here's the code revised (i've removed the first form element, i've adjusted the `action` of the second form, i've added `required` attributes to the inputs and textarea and i've updated the email input's type to "email" to make sure only valid emails are entered). Adding `required` should force modern browsers to prevent form submission if the inputs are not filled in properly.

```
<h1>Any enquiries:</h1>
<center>
<table width="700px">



<form id="contact_form" action="/pages/send_form" method="POST">

  <div class="row">
    <label for="name">Your Name:</label><br />
    <input id="name" class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30" required /><br />
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label for="email">Your Email:</label><br />
    <input id="email" class="input" name="email" type="email" value="" size="30" required /><br />
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label for="message">Your Message:</label><br />
    <textarea id="message" class="input" name="message" rows="7" cols="30" required></textarea><br />
  </div>
  <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send email" />

</form>
```